# Selenium, How to Reload a disabled image with chrome and python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': { 'images': 2}}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

I already know how to disable image loading in selenium.

However, while using it after disabling image loading, I would like to know how to reload the image in that tab if there is an image I want to see.

Comment: Do you mean fetch the image by the src and load that separately?